# How can I have multiple Client IDs in Google API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

How can I use 2 google APIs at the same time?
I have both client IDs but I can't seem to be able to get my script to ask for permission for both of the apis.

What do I need to change in Var Client ID or anything else to get 2 APIs to work at the same time? This is what I've tried:

```
 var CLIENT_ID = ['client ID 1', 'Client ID 2'] ;

 var CLIENT_ID = 'client ID 1', 'Client ID 2' ;

 var CLIENT_ID = 'client ID 1, Client ID 2' ;
```

Also what do I need to change about this function:

```
function initClient() {
gapi.client.init({
discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
clientId:CLIENT_ID,
scope: SCOPES
```

I am trying to use Drive API and Gmail API at the same time in the same script, how is that possible?

Comment: Please provide more details for example which 2 apis you need to use.

Comment: Gmail API and Drive API

Comment: @codemirror so is there anyway of using both clientIDs?

Comment: Call them both separately? What are you trying to solve with your approach?

Comment: @Joe I am trying to run GmailAPI and Drive API in the same script. How do I call them both separately?

Comment: I have a client Id for Drive API and a client Id for gmail API

Comment: Use the same client ID for both Drive API and for the Gmail API.

Answer (score -1):

To call multiple Google APIs using a single Client ID, just add the  necessary scope to be used by your apps.

Initial Scope:

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin', /** Default value **/
    scope: 'profile' }); /** Base scope **/
```

Request additional scopes:

```
var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
        {'scope': 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'});

googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
googleUser.grant(options).then(
    function(success){
      console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
    },
    function(fail){
      alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
    });
```

As a stated in the [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps), it is generally a best practice to request scopes incrementally, at the time access is required, rather than up front. For example, an app that wants to support purchases should not request Google Wallet access until the user presses the “buy” button; see [Incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth). There is no need to create multiple clientID for an application to access multiple Google APIs.

In your case, your initial scope would be either of the two then request for additional scope once the user access the method of the API. Also, check [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to see how the scope works.